# Python - can't import, nosetests throws error

Tags: python, python-2.7, path

I'm relatively new in Python and I just started working on making a skeleton directory to start distributing my projects and so. I followed the LPTHW book (exercise 46) and made the directories just like he said, but also read the documentation for the setup script and the Distutils.
I'm on my Windows now, and I built it this way:

```
C:\Python27\projects
            - skeleton
            - newproj
                 - (d) bin
                      - foo.py
                 - (d) docs
                 - (d) newproj
                      - __init__.py
                 - (d) tests
                      - __init__.py
                      - newproj_test.py
                 - setup.py
```

The setup.py is the same that the documentation's example:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name = 'foo',
      version = '1.0',
      py_modules = ['foo'],
      )
```

And in the '**init**' script there's something I don't really understand why, but:

```
from nose.tools import *
import foo

def setup():
    print "SETUP!"

def teardown():
    print "TEAR DOWN!"

def test_basic():
    print "I RAN!"
```

Inside newproj I have a bin directory in which I wrote a simple script called foo.py. The thing is that I open the Python interpreter and it doesn't find foo.py anywhere. If I go to the cmd, I would have to go all the way to C:\Python27\projects\newproj\bin and then type python, so I'm able to import foo. How could I change that? Is there any way to import things rather than going to the exact location of the script/module/program (dont know exactly the difference between these yet) to import it?

The real problem is that I'm supposed to run nosetests on the newproj directory and it shouldn't throw any error, but it does, it says that there's no module named foo, and I don't know what to do now, I kinda tried everything. I changed the Path variable to have these three: C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\projects

Comment: Your setup.py does not correspond to the one from [the exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html). Unrelated: I'm not sure about  `tests/__init__.py` (it creates top-level tests Python package) and `bin/foo.py` (unless you have dozens of scripts the `bin` directory does not justify the friction).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `C:\Python27\projects\newproj\bin` to your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

> I would have to go all the way to C:\Python27\projects\newproj\bin and then type python, so I'm able to import foo. How could I change that?

I am going through learn python the hard way too. One of the biggest mistakes beginners do is go all the way to the exact file location. NEVER do that !! in your case you should be at C:\Python27\projects\newproj then from there you type python in your shell and import foo using:

```
from bin import foo
```

but before you successfully import it you NEED to make sure you have 
an init.py file inside the directory your importing from.